# Get element name from XML in Java DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom

I want to get the element name and print the data in the XML, but not sure how to get data under specific element.

Here is the XML sample and my code.

```
   <mdb>
    <movies>
    <movie id="godfather">
      <title>The Godfather</title>
      <year>1972</year>
      <directors>
        <director idref="francisfordcoppola"/>
      </directors>
      <genres>
        <genre>Crime</genre>
        <genre>Drama</genre>
      </genres>
       <cast>
        <performer>
          <actor idref="marlonbrando"/>
          <role>Don Vito Corleone</role>
        </performer>
     </cast>
    </movie>
    </movies>

    <performer id="kimnovak">
      <name>Marilyn Pauline Novak</name>
      <dob>1933-02-13</dob>
      <pob>Chicago, Illinois, USA</pob>
      <actedin>
        <movie idref="vertigo"/>
      </actedin>
    </performer>
    </mdb>



try {
        File fXmlFile = new File(filename);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("movie");
         System.out.println("nodes length"+ nodes.getLength());
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++){
            Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
            NodeList name = element.getElementsByTagName("title");
            Element line = (Element) name.item(0);
            System.out.println(": " + line.getFirstChild().getTextContent());
```

I only want to get the element inside movie. but the following code also reads the
`<movie idref="vertigo"/>` inside the performer(causes Nullpointer exception if I want to get the content);  I'm wondering if there is any possible way to avoid read the  under Performance by using DOM?

```
NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("movie");
```

My final output for the first movie should look like this

```
('godfather', 'The Godfather', '1972', 'Crime;Drama')
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One way to do this is to start reading from movies tag instead of the movie tag. Not sure if this is what you are looking for !!.

```
NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("movies");

Element element = (Element) nodes.item(0);
NodeList movieList = element.getElementsByTagName("movie");
for (int i = 0; i < movieList.getLength(); i++) {
    Element movieElement = (Element) movieList.item(i);
    System.out.println(movieElement.getAttributes().getNamedItem("id").getNodeValue());
    NodeList name = movieElement.getElementsByTagName("title");
    NodeList year = movieElement.getElementsByTagName("year");
    NodeList genres = movieElement.getElementsByTagName("genres");
    Element genreline = (Element) genres.item(0);

    System.out.println(name.item(0).getFirstChild().getTextContent());
    System.out.println(year.item(0).getFirstChild().getTextContent());
    System.out.println(genreline.getElementsByTagName("genre").item(0).getTextContent() 
               + ":" + genreline.getElementsByTagName("genre").item(1).getTextContent());
}
```

Output :

> : godfather 
>   : The Godfather 
>   : 1972 
>   : Crime:Drama

Comment: Thanks, I need to use SAX or DOM. Do you think it;s posible in sax or dom?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you read up on [XPath](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html). Here are a few [examples](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_examples.asp).

For example, to read the year for your movies you could use the XPath...

```
/mdb/movies/movie/year/text()
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if it's possible to avoid read the <movie idref="vertigo"/> under Performance by using DOM?

Comment: That would be a separate question. I have rarely seen the need for such granularity in XML parsing of such data. If lookup speed is an issue than a XML is probably not your desired store.

Comment: then If I want to output all the data in all the movie. Do I have to create a path for each element or there is other short way?

Comment: Keep searching but yes... /mdb/movies/movie/*

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, this is my implementation,

```
public String getTagValue(org.w3c.dom.Document xmlDoc, String tagName) throws Exception {
        xmlDoc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(tagName);

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nodeList.getLength(); temp++) {
            Node nNode = nodeList.item(temp);
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                org.w3c.dom.Element eElement = (org.w3c.dom.Element) nNode;
                return eElement.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
            }
        }
        return "-1";
    }
```